# How can you batch process a directory of images using Intensify Pro?

Tags: mac, batch

I have a directory of 4000+ images that I took (timelapse). Since they are all nearly identical, I can be pretty certain that whatever tweaks I want to make to one can be blanket applied to all. How can I run all 4000+ of them through Intensify Pro with my desired tweaks?

http://macphun.com/intensifypro

Answer (score 0):

Received this response from Macphun (the developer):

> Hi Christopher - Thanks for the excellent question - sounds like an interesting project! Batching has been a popular request and it's something that we're definitely working on for a future release. Software doesn't currently support it however.

Would be interested in hearing if there is some way to automate it with some tool outside of the program...